# Advertised Shortcut not displaying in wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an advertised shortcut like given below

```
 <Component Id="comp1" Guid="{0EB394A2-1D7B-44A0-A85A-EC17E2816BDD}" KeyPath="yes">

    <Shortcut Id="Shortcut1" Directory="MyDir" Name="OfficeForms" ShortName="off~1" Description="officeformdesigns" Arguments="Filename.exe /x param" Icon="Icon.ico"  WorkingDirectory="FormDir" Advertise="yes"/>
  </Component>
```

But when the installer get installed this shortcut is not showing. When i didn't gave "Advertise" attribute shortcut got displayed but it is simply opening my [INSTALLDIR] folder and not the "Filename.exe /x param"

Also i am getting an ICE validation as given below.

Error  90  ICE50: Component 'comp1' has an advertised shortcut, but a null KeyPath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Advertised shortcuts should (must?) be nested under a `<File>` (the target the shortcut should launch) that is the keypath of the component.

for example

```
<Component Id="comp1" Guid="{0EB394A2-1D7B-44A0-A85A-EC17E2816BDD}" >
  <File Id="File.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.binDir)File.exe">
    <Shortcut Id="Shortcut1" Directory="MyDir" Name="OfficeForms" ShortName="off~1" Description="officeformdesigns" Arguments="/x param" Icon="Icon.ico"  WorkingDirectory="FormDir" Advertise="yes"/>
  </File>
</Component>
```